# error in submit button

Tags: asp.net, ms-access, vb6

I have an error in the execution of my code. It says **"Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement"**. This is my code:

```
Protected Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click GridView1.Visible = True

Dim myConn As OleDbConnection      
Dim sqlString, takenby, dest, client, car As String     
Dim recordno As Integer     
Dim dte, exptime As String      
recordno = TextBox4.Text     
dte = TextBox1.Text     
car = ComboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString()     
takenby = ComboBox2.SelectedValue.ToString     
dest = ComboBox3.SelectedValue.ToString     
client = TextBox2.Text     
exptime = TextBox3.Text      
myConn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\student\WebSite3\App_Data\Database.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;")      
myConn.Open()     
sqlString = "INSERT INTO DETAILED GISTEC CARS(Record No, Date, Car, Taken By, Destination, Client, Expected Time to Return)VALUES(?recordno, ?dte, ?car, ?takenby, ?dest, ?client, ?exptime);"      
Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlString, myConn)      
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()     
myConn.Close() 

End Sub
```

Comment: Edited to increase readability of code.

Comment: You have tagged this VB6 but the code you posted is VB.NET - which is it?

Answer (score 1):

You should change your query to use question mark placeholders and then add paramters to prevent (amongst other things) [sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i) issues.

You also need to add square brackets to your column names if they have spaces in them:

```
sqlString = "INSERT INTO [DETAILED GISTEC CARS] ([Record No], [Date], [Car], [Taken By], [Destination], [Client], [Expected Time to Return]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"

Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqlString, myConn)
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Record No", recordno))
cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Date", dte))
'etc
'etc
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

See [this page about OleDbParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute query directly in Access until it works.

From here it looks like

- You have no spaces around VALUES
- Your table name contain spaces so better use [] to surround table name
- Same with some column names.
- Not sure of ?recordno syntax in vb so better use + operator

`sqlString = "INSERT INTO [DETAILED GISTEC CARS]([Record No], [Date], [Car], [Taken By], [Destination], [Client], [Expected Time to Return]) VALUES (" + recordno + ", " + dte + ", " + car +", " + takenby, " + dest + ", " + client + ", " + exptime + ");"`

Comment: i tried using the ? and even @ but it dsnt work.... any idea? the problem is always at the execution.

what do u mean execute query directly in access? how can i do that?

Comment: Better use string concatenation as I have put. (Just edited).
Look for content of sqlstring and post it here so I can see final content. You can also execute in ms-access you can open access file directly  (Check this [link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/run-a-query-HA010077157.aspx) to see how to do it)

Comment: Good point, but SQL Injection is not suitable yet for someone doing vb6 + access :)

Comment: It is not just malicious SQL injection that you need to protect against. All it takes is one value to have a single quote in it for the whole query to fall over spectacularly. e.g. Surnames are a common source for this kind of error

Comment: I agree totally. Only that I thought it was too hard for someone that probably is learning at school. Upvoted your solution anyway because is better than mine  :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to cad's concatenation method would be to use curly brace array placeholders. Something like this should do it:

```
sqlString = String.Format("INSERT INTO [DETAILED GISTEC CARS] ([Record No], [Date], [Car], [Taken By], [Destination], [Client], [Expected Time to Return]) VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6});", recordno, dte, car, takenby, dest, client, exptime)
```

You should also put single quotes around non-numeric values, escape any user entered single quotes, and call the Access CDATE function for Date/Time columns. So, assuming `dte` is user entered data and `exptime` is a Date\Time column, those two variables might be set like this:

```
dte = "'" + TextBox1.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "'"
exptime = "CDATE('" + TextBox3.Text + "')"
```

and so on and so forth...

Comment: What do you think will happen if `dest` contains a single quote?

Comment: It would cause a syntax error in the query. You would essentially have a value that ends at the single quote and any subsequent characters would be unrecognised by the database engine.

Comment: Exactly my point! This is why you should use parameterised queries.

Comment: Um, look at my post again. I recommended using the `Replace` function to escape single quotes on user entered values. I fail to see how that's any less valid than using a parameterised query.

Comment: I would say less valid because it requires you to remember to escape single quotes, also what format is the db expecting the date variable dte to be in? Depending on locales you could at best get month and year mixed up and at worst the query could fail if it is not in the correct format.

Comment: Well again, I recommended using the Access CDATE function within the query, which correctly formats most date strings to the expected locale in exactly the same way a parameter does. I take your point about having to remember to do such things; although I must admit I wasn't aware parameters would deal with single quotes for you... we live and learn. :-)